# Require Method in Ruby

Tags: ruby, file, parameters, user-input, require

I have been searching around but I cant seem to find any answers for this problem.

I am required to write a program that will use the reflection methods built into ruby to tell me information about a class a user will specify.

I have this method:

```
def validFile(input)  
  filename = String.new()  
  filename = Dir.getwd + "/" + input  
  require(filename)  
end
```

however I get this error:

```
internal:lib/rubygems/customrequire:29:in 'require' no such file to load --         C:\Users\David\Ruby Projects\MyTestClass.rb
```

I am not sure why this doesn't work but this does:

```
def validFile(input)
  filename = Dir.getwd + "/MyTestClass.rb"
  require(filename)
end
```

This code doesn't help me because I have to have the user specify the file. I am using the gets method to get user input and that is being passed as a parameter to this method.

Are they not both strings? What am I doing wrong here? Additional note, I'm running the latest version of ruby on Windows 7. Thanks for the help.

Comment: just fyi, your filename = String.new() doesn't do anything, cause you are assigning a new value to filename right after

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just in case. Have you `chomp`ed the string that you got by `gets` before passing it as an argument? If you havn't, then it will contain extra carriage return characters at the end. You need to remove them like `input = gets.chomp`

Comment: This cleared it right up. Thanks for that. I feel really dumb now for the 2 hours I spent messing around with this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `File.exist?(filename)` to see if a file or directory exists. This should help narrow down the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, you're getting this input with `gets`.  Either `chomp` it in this method or use the more common idiom of `gets.chomp`.  So you can do something like this.

```
def do_require(input)
  require( Dir.getwd + "/" + input )
end

do_require gets.chomp
```